# how to create a save file dialog in html

Tags: html

Hi um new to html and I want to know the way to create a file save dialog box. It should not be a file open dialog box. is it possible to do in html ? I found these two components

```
 <input type="file" dialogtype="save" />
```

This creates a file upload dialog box though it mentioned the dialogtype as save

Comment: what exactly are you trying to allow the user to save? Couldn't you just let them download the file by redirecting them to the file?

Comment: thats because u have given input type as file,thats y it will open a file upload dialog box.

Comment: is there a way to create a file save dialog? I want to save a file which already in a server  to another location to the server

Comment: that u can do via cpanel,y u need to create a save dialog box explicitly for that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make download link ( Allowing user to download file server ). You can `<a>` tag to give server path. So when user click on the link browser will ask user to save the file.

Ex:

```
<a href="link/to/file.zip">Download</a>
```